# Solution verification: is that quantity bounded from below?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds

I would like to to draw your attention on a problem that my class mate posted earlier, showing you our idea for a possible solution.

Let $p>1, s>0$ and $F$ be a function such that
$$F(t)\le \frac{|t|^{p-p^{\prime}}}{p^{\prime}}e^{|t|^{p^{\prime}}}\quad\mbox{ for all } t\in\mathbb{R},$$
where $p^{\prime}$ denotes the conjugate exponent of $p$.
We are wondering if the quantity
$$\frac{|t|^p}{s+1} e^{|t|^{p^{\prime}}} -2N F(t)$$
is bounded from below.
We guess the answer would be yes because we have
$$\frac{|t|^p}{s+1} e^{|t|^{p^{\prime}}} -2N F(t)\ge |t|^p e^{|t|^{p^{\prime}}}(1/(s+1)-2(N-1))|t|^{-p^{\prime}}$$
which seems to me it is bounded from below.

Could someone please tell me if are we wrong or not?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can we assume $0 < p'$?

Comment: @MattWerenski thank you for the comment. I edited the question specifying that $p^{\prime}$ is the conjugate exponent of $p$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim only holds for $N \geq 0$ and $p \geq 2$.

To see why you need $N \geq 0$, note that if $N < 0$ then
$$\frac{|t|^p}{s+1}e^{|t|^{p'}} - 2NF(t) = \frac{|t|^p}{s+1}e^{|t|^{p'}} + CF(t)$$
for $C = -2N > 0$ and since there is no *lower bound* on $F(t)$ one cannot say whether or not this expression is bounded below. For example, let $F(t) = -1/|t|$ and choose $t$ close to 0.

Now lets look at the more subtle issue. If $p \in (1,2)$ then it's conjugate satisfies
$$
p' = \frac{p}{p-1} \implies (p-1)p' = p \implies p' > p
$$
where the last implication is from the fact that $p-1 \in (0,1)$. Now using this we have for $p \in 1,2$ that $p-p' < 0$. From here we have
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{|t|^{p-p'}}{p'} e^{|t|^{p'}} \geq \frac{1}{p'} \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} |t|^{p-p'} = \infty$$
since $e^{|t|^{p'}} \geq 1$ and $p-p' < 0$.

Now for $t \in [-1,1]$ we have
$$\frac{|t|^p}{s+1} e^{|t|^p} \leq \frac{1}{s+1}e^1 = \frac{e}{s+1}.$$ Now consider the function when $F(t) = \frac{|t|^{p-p'}}{p'}e^{|t|^{p'}}$, which satisfies the upper bound in the assumption (just with equality everywhere). Then
\begin{align}
   \lim_{t\in[-1,1], t\rightarrow 0} \frac{|t|^p}{s+1} e^{|t|^p} - 2NF(t) 
&= \lim_{t\in[-1,1], t\rightarrow 0} \frac{|t|^p}{s+1} e^{|t|^p} - 2N\frac{|t|^{p-p'}}{p'}e^{|t|^{p'}} \\
&\leq \lim_{t\in[-1,1], t\rightarrow 0} \frac{e}{s+1} - 2N\frac{|t|^{p-p'}}{p'}e^{|t|^{p'}} \\
&= \frac{e}{s+1} - 2N\lim_{t \in [-,1,1], t \rightarrow 0} \frac{|t|^{p-p'}}{p'} e^{|t|^{p'}} \\
&= -\infty
\end{align}
since the last limit was already shown to go to $+\infty$ and we have $N > 0$. This shows, even though the function isn't well-defined at $t = 0$, by choosing $t$ close enough to 0 it can be driven arbitrarily low. Or in other words, the quantity is not bounded below.

Now when $p \geq 2$ this problem doesn't happen since $p' \leq p$. In particular, by the assumptions
$$\frac{|t|^p}{s+1}e^{|t|^{p'}} - 2NF(t) \geq \frac{|t|^p}{s+1}e^{|t|^{p'}} - 2N \frac{|t|^{p-p'}}{p'}e^{|t|^{p'}}.$$
This lower bound is a continuous function. Let's check where it can be negative
\begin{align} 
\frac{|t|^p}{s+1}e^{|t|^{p'}} - 2N \frac{|t|^{p-p'}}{p'}e^{|t|^{p'}} &\leq 0 \\
\iff \frac{|t|^p}{s+1}e^{|t|^{p'}} &\leq 2N \frac{|t|^{p-p'}}{p'}e^{|t|^{p'}} \\
\iff \frac{|t|^p}{s+1} &\leq 2N \frac{|t|^{p-p'}}{p'} \\
\iff |t|^{p'} &\leq \frac{2N(s+1)}{p'} \\
\iff |t| &\leq \left ( \frac{2N(s+1)}{p'} \right )^{1/p'}
\end{align}
Outside the interval $\left [-\left ( \frac{2N(s+1)}{p'} \right )^{1/p'}, \left ( \frac{2N(s+1)}{p'} \right )^{1/p'} \right ]$ the lower bound is further bounded below by zero. On this interval, the lower bound is a continuous function on a compact interval which implies it achieves a finite minimum (this is a standard analysis fact). In particular let it's minimum on the interval be $M > -\infty$. Then we have the lower bound is further bounded by $M^* = \min(0,M)$. Remembering we are lower bounding a lower bound we have
$$\frac{|t|^p}{s+1}e^{|t|^{p'}} - 2NF(t) \geq \frac{|t|^p}{s+1}e^{|t|^{p'}} - 2N \frac{|t|^{p-p'}}{p'}e^{|t|^{p'}} \geq M^*$$
which shows that the quantity of interest is indeed lower bounded.

Comment: Matt Werenski, thank you for the answer. I don't understand why, in the case $p\ge 2$, in the last steps of the chain of iff, you get rid of$|\cdot|$. I think that mantaining that, you can directly say that the function is bounded from below by $0$.

Comment: I've added back in the $|\cdot|$, I forgot them on accident. I don't agree though that the function is bounded below by 0 uniformly. If $N \rightarrow \infty$ then it can be made to go as far below 0 as you want. The main point is that as $|t|$ grows, the function tends to $+\infty$, but you need something stronger to say that there is a lower bound.